# Как брать данные с помощью rxjava из обьекта по условию ??

Tags: java, android, rxjava

Есть задача.Получить при воходе в приложение проверить бд на наличие данных , если их нет то получить их из сети записать в бд и взять их с бд 
я сделал так

```
  return Observable.mergeDelayError(
            ewsRemoteRepository.getInboxFolderMessage()
                    .doOnNext(inboxModels -> ewsLocalRepository.inserAll(inboxModels)
                    ).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()),
            ewsLocalRepository.getAllInboxMessage()
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()))}
```

Но эт о сразу полачает и записывает в бд а как сделать чтоб сперва проверял данные с бд и потом уже делал эту операцию

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По идее, если `ewsLocalRepository.getAllInboxMessage()` будет возвращать `Maybe`, то можно как-то так сделать (код не проверял, может не скомпилироваться):

```
ewsLocalRepository.getAllInboxMessage()
    .andThen(() -> ewsRemoteRepository.getInboxFolderMessage()
                    .doOnNext(inboxModels -> ewsLocalRepository.inserAll(inboxModels)
                    .ewsLocalRepository.getAllInboxMessage())
```

Comment: да сойдет ) но я взял flatmap   и написаол проверку)